# is it possible to sync two tables in two linked server one from MySQL and MSSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have created two Linked server one from Mysql and the other from remote MSSQL. is it possible to sync tables in these two Linked server from different database?

Comment: you should be able to manually compare and sync these linked server tables using some key column(s) using a scheduled SQL Job. without exact table structure, its hard to formulate this into an actual answer

Comment: Thank @ughai  Can you show me sample Insert statement - syntax?

Comment: just do a normal `Insert into MySQLLnkedServer...TableName(Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM SQLServerLinkedServer.database.schema.TableName`

Comment: thanks if i want to go the reverse side `Insert into XX-SERVER.database.schema.TableName 
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM MySQLLnkedServer...TableName(Col1,Col2)` or if i want to insert data into MSSQL from  Mysql?

Comment: @Kin I suggest you to use Navicat Premium(Version 10.0.10)third party tool for database synchronization. It is very helpful for data synchronization and structure synchronization. I was also facing like that issue but i solved it by using this tool.

Comment: Thanks @JarYit does it sync tabless in MYSQL and MSSQL ?

Comment: Thanks thats is a good new  i will probably get that

Answer (score 2):

To Insert data from MySQL to SQL Server, do something like

```
INSERT INTO SQLServerLinkedServer.database.schema.TableName(Col1,Col2)
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM MySQLinkedServer...TableName
```

To Insert data from SQL Server to MySQL, do something like

```
INSERT INTO MySQLinkedServer...TableName(Col1,Col2)
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM SQLServerLinkedServer.database.schema.TableName
```

You can compare these tables using key column. For Example insert missing records in MySQLinkedServer using something like this

```
INSERT INTO MySQLinkedServer...TableName(Col1,Col2)
SELECT T1.Col1,T2.Col2 
FROM SQLServerLinkedServer.database.schema.TableName T1
    LEFT JOIN MySQLinkedServer...TableName T2
    ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
WHERE T2.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: My Linked server to MSSQL name is like XXX-SERVER. the word `SERVER`  auto highlighted in blue becasue `SERVER` is a keyword. Can i use `INSERT INTO 'XXX-SERVER'.database.schema.TableName(Col1,Col2) instead? Single quote?

Comment: just quote the server name with [] like this`[XXX-Server]`. please check the following [identifier rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot but i get this error `Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider MSDASQL for linked server MYODBC reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7372, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get properties from OLE DB provider MSDASQL for linked server MYODBC.` MYODBC is is MYSQL Data source name

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with your linked server configuration. check your steps with [this](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/)